# One Db type to another - SQL

Tags: sql-server, etl, ravendb, document-based-database

If I have SQL tables tblA and tblB and they have one to many relationship between them.. can we create multiple raven db documents automatically .. Can I automatically load documents in Raven DB... from SQL server tables any other way... using any tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [ETL demo](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/ETL) in Raven's code base.

Additionally, you may have a look at how [Raccoon imports](https://github.com/fitzchak1/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/src/RaccoonBlog.ImportFromSubtext/Program.cs#L75) a SQL database for Subtext into RavenDB.